# How to reorder the address in sales order csv

Tags: magento2

I Want to reorder address data in sales order CSV instead of address displaying in this order (street, City, Region, Postal code ), I want to show it in this order(Postal code, Region, City, Street).

Comment: In the sale order CSV file I want to change the position of the street, postcode, city, region in this format postcode, region, city, street.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this from admin. Location:

***Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> Address Templates***

[image]

Change **HTML** value.

Comment: thanks for the reply but while extracting CSV it doesn't change.